# Understanding recursive factorial function in NASM Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, recursion, nasm, 32-bit

Learning NASM Assembly on 32-bit Ubuntu. I'm now trying to learn about recursive functions, starting with factorial (note: here I am assuming that the parameter will always be non-negative).

Assuming that I have

```
push 3
call factorial
```

I want to end up with `6` in `EAX`.

Here is my attempt:

```
SECTION .text
global main
main:
; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Main
; -----------------------------------------------------------
push    3
call    factorial

; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Exit
; -----------------------------------------------------------
mov EAX,1
int 0x80

; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Recursive Factorial: n! = n * (n - 1)!
; -----------------------------------------------------------
factorial:

push    EBP         ; Retrieve parameter and put it
mov     EBP,ESP     ; into EBX register
add     EBP,8       ;
mov     EBX,[EBP]   ; EBX = Param

cmp     EBX,0       ; Check for base case
je      base        ; It is base if (n == 0)

dec     EBX         ; Decrement EBX to put it in the stack
push    EBX         ; Put (EBX - 1) in stack
inc     EBX         ; Restore EBX
call    factorial   ; Calculate factorial for (EBX - 1)
mul     EBX         ; EAX = (EAX * EBX) = (EBX - 1)! * EBX
pop     EBX         ; Retrieve EBX from the stack

jmp end
base:               ; Base case
mov     EAX,1       ; The result would be 1

end:

pop     EBP         ; Release EBP
ret
```

At least it works for the base case, ha... But for any other value I push, it always returns `0`. I had the suspicion that maybe since `EAX` is `0`, `MUL` would always result in `0`, explaining this. To test, I decided to give `EAX` a value of `2`, expecting some non-zero value, but it kept resulting in `0`.

Can you advice me on how to do a recursive factorial function that takes its parameter from the stack? I believe having seen some examples, but either they were not recursive or they took their parameters from other places, or they used a bunch of variables (when I think it can be done with just registers).

Comment: Hint: write the function in C, compile with `gcc -Wall -O3 -m32 -S ...` then use the resulting compiler-generated asm source as a template for your own function (or even just for general guidance on managing the stack, passing params and function results, etc).

Comment: @PaulR: Thank you for the advice. Someone once told me about a site that translated C++ to Assembly (http://assembly.ynh.io/), do you think that's any good for this purpose as well?

Comment: Since you're running Linux you already have all the tools you need (i.e. gcc) but you can never have too many tools and if the site can generate asm in Intel format suitable for NASM then it might be more useful to you in this particular case. Try both anyway - it's a good way to learn stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `factorial(n-1)` will overwrite `factorial(n)'s` value of `EBX` the first thing it does, thereby rendering the `inc EBX` after the `push` pointless. After you've reached the base case you'll have the situation where `EBX` is 0 when you do the `mul`, and of course anything * 0 == 0.

The easiest fix would be to change the prologue to:

```
push    EBP         ; Retrieve parameter and put it
push    EBX         ; save previous param
mov     EBP,ESP     ; into EBX register
add     EBP,12       ;
mov     EBX,[EBP]   ; EBX = Param
```

And the epilogue to:

```
pop     EBX         ; restore previous param
pop     EBP         ; Release EBP
ret
```